# How to access the ActionMailer from name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have an ActionMailer that has a variable from NAME, thus I would like to test that the name is being properly set.

In short:

```
  def test_email()
    mail({
      :from    => '"John Smith"<john@smith.com>'
    })
  end
```

If I then generate a mailer and try to access the from...

```
$ m = UserMailer.test_email
$ m.from
=> ["john@smith.com"]
```

I just get the email address. How do I access the "John Smith" part?

Comment: Can you try to format the ``from:`` like this? ``'John Smith <john@smith.com>'``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between the string you pass into mail (which will be included as the `From:` header) and the actual email address that the mail is from (and hence which will be used in the SMTP `MAIL FROM` command).

If you want to see the value that you passed in then use:

```
m[:from].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract it from the headers like so.

```
m.header.select { |i| i.name == "From" }.first.value[/\"(.*?)\"/,0]
```

If you want to remove the doubt quotes as well do:

```
m.header.select { |i| i.name == "From" }.first.value[/\"(.*?)\"/,0][1..-2]
```